# How to write log lines to files in disk, if redis fails, while using redis-logback-appender?

Tags: java, redis, logback

I am using a logback redis appender to store logback logs to redis. The pom dependency for redis-logback-appender is given below.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cwbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-redis-appender</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The logback.xml file is shown below. As a fallback mechanism, I need the logfiles to be stored in local disk if redis fails.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
    <timestamp key="byDay" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss" />
    <appender name="LOGSTASH" class="com.cwbase.logback.RedisAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %-5line %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
        <host>localhost</host>
        <port>6379</port>
        <source>my-test-app</source>
        <type>test</type>
        <key>my-testlog-app</key>
    </appender>
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="LOGSTASH" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to configure the logback.xml to write log lines to files in disk if redis fails?

Answer (score 3):

write a log-file using JSON, something like:

```
<configuration>
    <timestamp key="byDay" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"/>
    <appender name="LOGSTASH" class="com.cwbase.logback.RedisAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %-5line %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
        <host>localhost</host>
        <port>6379</port>
        <source>my-test-app</source>
        <type>test</type>
        <key>my-testlog-app</key>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="LOGSTASH"/>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>testFile.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout">
                <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter">
                    <!-- prettyPrint is probably ok in dev, but usually not ideal in production: -->
                    <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
                </jsonFormatter>
                <context>api</context>
                <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'</timestampFormat>
                <timestampFormatTimezoneId>UTC</timestampFormatTimezoneId>
                <appendLineSeparator>true</appendLineSeparator>
            </layout>
            <!-- <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern> -->
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I also added the async appender because a slow/unavailable Redis will slow down/break your application since all Redis communication is synchronous using TCP. Using logstash to parse a continuous JSON stream from your log file or using GELF can decouple things, so your application is not harmed.